# How to get Comma seperated string in Codeigniter and compare with session id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, ipad

Guyz I need help in CodeIgniter SQL query,
I have one calendar table and id store like 1,2,3.... so now I want a record those match with the session id in CodeIgniter so how I can do this
Here I put my table image so please check it
[Calender Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVRT2.png)
So how can I split this id and compare with session id

```
    <?php
public function projectuser()
{
    $data['test'] = $this->main_model->getproject();
    $data['get_cat'] = $this->main_model->getprojectid();
    $this->load->view('projectuser',$data);
}

?>
```

MODEL:

```
    public function getproject() {

  $data = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
  $this->db->select("*");
  $this->db->from("user_registration");
  $this->db->join('calendar','user_registration.user_id=calendar.user_id', 'INNER');
  $this->db->where('user_registration.user_id', $data);
  $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}

public function getprojectid() {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("calendar");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

VIEW:

```
   foreach ($test as $val) {
            $array = explode(",", $val->user_id); // GET ALL IS
            echo $val->title .'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
          }

          foreach ($get_cat as $key => $value) {

            if (in_array($value->user_id, $array)) {
             echo $value->user_id .'&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/>'; //COMPARE WITH SESS

           }
         }
```

Comment: without any code it is difficult

Comment: I tried using query but it didn't get any output

Comment: I also tried using explode function but didn't match with session id

Comment: Please read about `FIND_IN_SET`

Comment: so lets say everything works fine and you got your field right and its a string like this `"1,2,3,4,5,..."` and you exploded it and your session_id is like this `"3"` and you used `in_array` and it is true so what is the problem?

Comment: yes sir everything is fine, but problem is that,
suppose i am login with user_id no 2 so its not working

Comment: Please check my model query, if any problem in query then let me inform

Comment: I still don't get it PLEASE explain in DETAILS what do you mean by when you login with user_id no.2 it doesn't work? do you mean in_array fails or do you mean when you login with another user it doesn't work? or what?

Comment: yes sir exactly.

Comment: i asked two question so "exactly" for what?

Comment: user_id no 2 doesn't work.

Comment: Can you confirm then that your comma separated string is right? cause other wise it doesn't make any sense it got to be wrong.

Comment: yes sir i am sure about string is correct,
Let me try by myself,
your logic is correct so Thank you for help,
i appreciate your work so i am up vote your answer

Comment: I've updated my answer and corrected your code @jaydev vara .. your check was wrong we want to check that the `$session_user_id` is in the `$field_user_id`

Comment: btw, keep your logic in the controller not the view, views are meant for presentations not calculations.

Comment: i checked your ans but it giving not notice error

Message: Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object

Comment: yeah sir,
thank you 
enjoy coding

Comment: Yeah i know cause your session is an array not an object, i'm not writing it exactly as it should be, i'm just telling you how to do .. it should be something like this `$this->session->user_data('user_id');`

Comment: okok sir.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your comma separated string to an array using `explode` then check if your session id is in that array using `in_array`

that's if already queried that string

```
$array = explode(',', $comma_separated_values);
if(in_array($session_id, $array)
{
    // do your magic
}
```

but if you wanna a sql query you can try this:

`SELECT whatever WHERE FIND_IN_SET($session_id, comma_separated_field)`

---

i've corrected your code here:

```
foreach ($get_cat as $key => $value) 
{
    $array = explode(',', $value->user_id);
    if (in_array($data->user_id, $array))
    {
        echo $value->user_id .'&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/>'; //COMPARE WITH SESS
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it but one little problem, only get first value,
like 1,2,3 is id so only get 1
now suppose 2nd number is login then it did not get any result

Comment: foreach ($test as $val) {
                $array = explode(",", $val->user_id); // GET ALL IS
                echo $val->title .'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
              }

              foreach ($get_cat as $key => $value) {

                if (in_array($value->user_id, $array)) {
                 echo $value->user_id .'&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/>'; //COMPARE 

               }
             }

Comment: You want to search for multiple values in the comma separated string, not a single entry?

Comment: i dont get this what you say can you explain more please

Comment: What exactly do want to achieve? .. what i got is that you want to search if an ID stored in your session exists in a comma separated field in your array and i wrote two ways to do so, one with sql query and one with php code, now you want something else that i don't understand so please clarify!

Comment: its only provide first user_id  values
suppose 1,2,3 is id so only consider 1 not others
Ex. suppose am login with 2 no id then its not giving any result

Comment: And what do want it to provide, please modify your question and explain in details what do want given an example.

Comment: I updated my question so please look at that @Sherif salah